# iter() alternative for awaitables?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Usually in IO operations we use `iter()` to read up to sentinel value:

```
from sys import stdout

with open(r"Z:\github\StackOverFlow\temp.json", "r") as fp:
    for chunk in iter(lambda :fp.read(64), ""):
        stdout.write(chunk)
```

But is there alternative to `iter()` for awaitable, i.e. `asyncio.Queue.get()`?

```py
for val in iter(lambda: await queue.get(), sentinel):
    queue.task_done()
    print(val)
```

Surely this won't work as while it requires callable, `await` can't be called inside non-async functions.

Situation does not allow `queue.get_nowait()` as queue is empty for most of time.

---

Simple fix would be using `while` loop:

```py
while True:
    if (val := await queue.get()) is None:
        break
    queue.task_done()
    print(val)
```

But I'm afraid if this harms readability and clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve what you used with the `while` loop to integrate the walrus into the `while` conditional:

```
while (val := await queue.get()) is not None:
    queue.task_done()
    print(val)
```

which gets you to equivalent brevity of your desired result, and isn't particularly ugly relative to your desired two-arg `iter` solution (two-arg `iter` being a relatively ugly thing to use in the first place).

Comment: Forgot simple fact that ```while``` can have expressions, mybad. Actually I was expecting answers would require extensive use of ```async for```, ```__anext__``` and ```__aiter__```.

Comment: Hoped if there's something like ```aiter()``` in the first place - but it seems like l was just following ```iter()``` patterns in *Python Cookbook 3E* without considering book was based on *3.4* not *3.8*, where walrus operator first appeared.

Comment: @jupiterbjy: Yeah, not really. Queues aren't built for `for` loops (as you can see by the hackiness of two-arg `iter` that you needed to make it work with a regular `for` loop); if that was an intended use case, they'd have made them iterable in the first place. Now that we've got the walrus operator, we don't really need the hacks anyway (most of my old two-arg `iter` uses are best done with `while walrus`, e.g. `while block := f.read(1024):` is nicer than `for block in iter(functools.partial(f.read, 1024), b''):`), and it's the most straightforward solution for your case too.

Comment: Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules - which I've violated via iterating non-iterable, thanks for clarifying up.

Answer (score 1):

PEP 525 that introduced asynchronous generators in Python 3.6 actually [proposes built-in `aiter` and `anext`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#aiter-and-anext-builtins) in Python 3.7. And we know that that didn't happen. Looking at the discussion in corresponding [BPO-31861](https://bugs.python.org/issue31861), that still may happen but not earlier than Python 3.10.

But there's the CPython [BPO PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8895) with early implementation. There's still discussion whether it should be implemented in Python or C, live in `operator` module or `builtins`, but it seems the Python version can already be employed. Including the code verbatim as of [908227bb](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8895/commits/908227bbdd15de195be):

```py
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable, AsyncIterator


_NOT_PROVIDED = object()  # sentinel object to detect when a kwarg was not given


def aiter(obj, sentinel=_NOT_PROVIDED):
    """aiter(async_iterable) -> async_iterator
    aiter(async_callable, sentinel) -> async_iterator
    Like the iter() builtin but for async iterables and callables.
    """
    if sentinel is _NOT_PROVIDED:
        if not isinstance(obj, AsyncIterable):
            raise TypeError(f'aiter expected an AsyncIterable, got {type(obj)}')
        if isinstance(obj, AsyncIterator):
            return obj
        return (i async for i in obj)

    if not callable(obj):
        raise TypeError(f'aiter expected an async callable, got {type(obj)}')

    async def ait():
        while True:
            value = await obj()
            if value == sentinel:
                break
            yield value

    return ait()
```

Comment: Already ```async for``` is highly restricted, to see it in ```aiter``` implementation I suspect it might not be widely used, but still happy to see it in future. Can't appreciate more for these precious documents

Comment: Plus, I expected it to accept coroutines, but it's getting ```callable``` instead, which is kind of weird to think that it's ```aiter``` not ```iter```. Or is ```async callable``` a coroutine?

Comment: A coroutine function is a callable. I think it's intended to support a callable that just returns `Future`s like `f1 = asyncio.Future(); f1.set_result(42); f2 = asyncio.Future(); f2.set_result(None); [v async for v in aiter([f2, f1].pop, None)]`.

Comment: That looks more like an hack - but since it's on proposal rather than actual code, things might be tided up later I suspect?

Comment: I doubt `aiter` will have different signature. It's in line with `asyncio` API (where many things are `Future`-based). It progressed naturally from Tulip to what it is now, so it has design issues which don't make it impractical though. For more details read renowned [Nathaniel J. Smith's article on the topic](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/).

Comment: That even deals socket problem I was struggling with - thanks for link, might take some days to analyze and reply.

Comment: Brought hard copy of that essay up mountain, read it for full month - Seems like *Trio* is now mature enough, and has pretty much of ecosystems around it. Definitely fits my taste.